# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Access Point

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi

I have followed the following tutorial to set up an wifi access point:

- https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/
- https://gary-dalton.github.io/RaspberryPi-projects/rpi3_simple_wifi_ap.html

After configuring hostapd, i've tested the setup with

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

and recieved the following error:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported)
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr b8:27:eb:3d:60:0c and ssid "Pi3-AP"
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED
```

In my sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

#iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth0
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.16.164.145
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 172.16.164.255
    gateway 172.16.164.254
    dns-nameservers 172.22.16.98

allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet static
    address 172.16.164.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.16.164.0
    broadcast 172.16.164.255

#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

#allow-hotplug wlan1
#iface wlan1 inet manual
#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

In my sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
# This is the name of the WiFi interface we configured above
interface=wlan0

# Use the nl80211 driver with the brcmfmac driver
driver=nl80211

# This is the name of the network
ssid=Pi3-AP

# Use the 2.4GHz band
hw_mode=g

# Use channel 6
channel=6

# Enable 802.11n
ieee80211n=1

# Enable WMM
wmm_enabled=1

# Enable 40MHz channels with 20ns guard interval
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]

# Accept all MAC addresses
macaddr_acl=0

# Use WPA authentication
auth_algs=1

# Require clients to know the network name
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# Use WPA2
wpa=2

# Use a pre-shared key
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

# The network passphrase
wpa_passphrase=raspberry

# Use AES, instead of TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

I would appericate any help to solve this problem. I am a totally beginner in Raspberry Pi and Linux.

Much appreciated

Comment: Try using these instructions: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point

Answer (score 3):

Do you see the AP with your phone or laptop? In the [raspberry.org forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=141807) the same issue (after following the same tutorial) has been discussed. The user allfox mentioned this error is a result of implementation delays...

If you start the hostapd with

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

or

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

You should see something like:

```
nl80211: Driver does not support monitor interface type - try to run without it
```

but the AP should be visible.

***Edit:***

Assuming that that the LAN where you connect your eth0 port of your Raspberry already runs a DHCP (which would make a static IP there a source for conflicts) you can configure your Pi like this:

Remove the dnsmasq AND hostapd and all related config files:

```
sudo apt-get purge dnsmasq hostapd
```

Install hostapd and bridging tools:

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd bridge-utils
```

The interface config should look like this /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Localhost
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Ethernet
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
# Ethernet VLAN for config
auto eth0.1
allow-hotplug eth0.1
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# WLAN
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wireless-power off

# bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
pre-up ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
pre-up ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0 up
pre-up brctl addbr br0
pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0
post-down ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0 down
post-down ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 down
post-down brctl delif br0 eth0
post-down brctl delbr br0
```

The bridge will **replace** the eth0 so you cant access this interface anymore. The eth0.1 will be a virtual interface that get also an IP from the DHCP of your LAN.
If you reboot, the pi should be accessible over this eth0.1 interface and the IP address provided by your router.
You can check with

```
brctl show
```

if the bridge is working.

Your hostapd config in the /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf file should look like this

```
bridge=br0

interface=wlan0
#driver=nl80211


ssid=Pi3AP
channel=1
hw_mode=g
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211d=1
wmm_enabled=1


auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=badpassword
```

Test if the AP comes up:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

If the AP comes up and you can connect with a device to it, you can daemonize it by editing /etc/default/hostapd

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

After rebooting the AP should become visible after less than 3 minutes.

This edit is based on a tutorial of [Lawrence](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/1254/lawrence) on his [blog here](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/09/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-1/) and [here](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/10/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-2/) and this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14318/wifi-accesspoint-bridged-to-lan-transparently) to a bridging question. I run a similar config on a RPi2.

Comment: I am unable to see the AP on my phone.

Comment: I used the command above that you have provided, i did see something like u have mentioned. However the AP is not visible

Comment: i dont have a RPi 3 here at the moment.... i can update my PRi2 AP configuration and post it here...Please type lsusb and post the output

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:002f Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: does your LAN has a DHCP on the router or do you have static IP addresses?

Comment: How do i check whether my LAN has a DHCP on the router? I think i got static IP address in the sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: can you connect with other devices to your router/network? A Laptop or smart phone? If yes and you doesn't need to configure an IP there, a DHCP is running on your router. On Windows  it works like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/270528/how-can-i-tell-if-my-ip-is-static-or-assigned-by-dhcp-on-windows-7) (also on Win10)

Comment: I am trying to Install hostapd and bridging tools that u have provided me with the command, however it states that i am unable to locate the E: Unable to locate package brutils

Comment: okay my mistake.... the command is `sudo apt-get install bridge-utils` I will update this above.

Comment: @Nicholas, did it work?

Comment: In the  /etc/network/interfaces with the commands that u have given me, then i rebooted it, there is no internet. Then i use the command brctl show, this is what i get. bridge name br0, bridge id 8000.b827ebdeadd2, STP enabled no, interfaces eth0

Comment: there is missing the wlan0 interface in the bridge. please list the interfaces of your RPi: `ip link show`

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:de:ad:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:8b:f8:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: 4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:de:ad:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: seems to be ok. check the content of your /etc/network/interfaces there must be a reason, why wlan0 is not a part of the bridge

Comment: you can try to kill the bridge `brctl delbr br0` then `ip addr flush dev eth0` same for wlan0 `ip addr flush dev wlan0`. then create a new bridge `brctl addbr br123` and add there the interfaces `brctl addif br123 eth0 wla0` then bring the bridge up `ip link set dev br123` up

Comment: I manage to do until brctl addif br123 eth0 wlan0, however it says that "can't add wlan0 to bridge br123: Operation not supported"

Comment: edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and remove comment(#) the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Answer (score 1):

Use "***pi-ap***"- a Github repo which automates the configuration of a Pi 3 (or Pi 4) into a WiFi AP.  Really, **REALLY** simple to use.  Just edit `variables.sh` and change some default values, and then `sudo ./install.sh` will get you a working Pi Access Point in about 3.5 minutes while you drink your tea.

Only need a Pi 3B+ or a Pi 4, an Ethernet cable and a router with an Internet connection to uplink the Pi to and you're good to go:

https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap/

The `install.sh` script calls all the other dependent scripts which source that `variables.sh` file and a few minutes later a working Access Point comes out the other end of the sausage maker.  There's a detailed `README.md` in the repo and a Wiki for it in Github for support.  HTH- T

Answer (score 0):

To Configure an Acess Point out of a Raspberry I've made a Shell-Script for a Student Project. 
 https://github.com/Doriangaensslen/pren1/raspberry_installation_scripts/wlan_activate.sh

Execute it only on a clean Raspberry